# making a 3D quiver plot using matplotlib by reading in data

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to make a 3D quiver plot using matplotlib 2.2.5.    I provide a simple sample code below to show my attempt.  I want to make a quiver plot using fx(x,y,z), fy(x,y,z) and fz(x,y,z).  These correspond to the vector field f = (fx,fy,fz).  I input the data for fx,fy,fz as 3 .dat files where each .dat file is 1 column of numbers.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #I'm using matplotlib 2.2.5
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

fx = np.genfromtxt('fx.dat')
fy = np.genfromtxt('fy.dat')
fz = np.genfromtxt('fz.dat')

N = 10
Fx = fx[::N,::N]
Fy = fy[::N,::N]
Fz = fz[::N,::N]

nrows, ncols = Fx.shape
nx = 1
ny = 1
nz = 1

x = np.linspace(-nx, nx, ncols)
y = np.linspace(-ny, ny, ncols)
z = np.linspace(-nz, nz, ncols)
xi, yi, zi = np.meshgrid(x, y, z, indexing='ij')

plt.quiver(xi, yi, zi, Fx, Fy, Fz, edgecolor='k', facecolor='black', linewidth=.5)

plt.axis('scaled')
plt.show()
```

The data is generated and stored as follows (using fortran):

```
!generate data
DO i = -nx,nx !nx = 1
  DO j = -ny,ny !ny = 1
     DO k = -nz,nz !nz = 1
       fx(i,j,k) = i + 2.*j  + 3.*k  !this is a function fx that depends on x,y,z; fx(x,y,z)
       fy(i,j,k) = i - 4.*j  + k !this is a function fy that depends on x,y,z; fy(x,y,z)
       fz(i,j,k) = i + 2*j + k !this is a function fz that depends on x,y,z; fz(x,y,z)
     END DO
  END DO
END DO

!store data
DO i = -nx,nx
   DO j = -ny,ny
      DO k = -nz,nz
        WRITE(1,*) fx(i,j,k) !stores fx(x,y,z)
        WRITE(2,*) fy(i,j,k) !stores fy(x,y,z)
        WRITE(3,*) fz(i,j,k) !stores fz(x,y,z)
      END DO
   END DO
END DO
```

Comment: I'm voting to close the question because it doesn't have the data file associated with the question, which makes the question and answer not reproducible, and therefore not helpful to the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming here you are trying to plot the quivers starting from the (origin (0,0,0)).

Using a random sample with coordinates between -1 and 1 (hoping it will match your data sample), this would go this way:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

fx = np.genfromtxt('fx.dat')
fy = np.genfromtxt('fy.dat')
fz = np.genfromtxt('fz.dat')

N = 10
Fx = fx[:N]
Fy = fy[:N]
Fz = fz[:N]
```

*Note that I used a simple ":": based on your explanation, your .dat files have only one dimension. You use multiples colon only if you have at least 2 dimensions.*

```
plt.quiver(0, 0, 0, Fx, Fy, Fz, edgecolor='k', facecolor='black', linewidth=.5) #To plot starting from the origin

ax.set_xlim(-1,1)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
ax.set_zlim(-1,1)

plt.show()
```

If you want to plot starting from your mesh (ie np.linspace), you can alter the code as follow (though I'm not sure this is what you are trying to achieve):

```
nx = 1
ny = 1
nz = 1
x = np.linspace(-nx, nx, N)
y = np.linspace(-ny, ny, N)
z = np.linspace(-nz, nz, N)
plt.quiver(x, y, z, Fx, Fy, Fz, edgecolor='k', facecolor='black', linewidth=.5)
ax.set_xlim(-2,2) #I altered the bounds to match the new coordinates 
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_zlim(-2,2)
```

Note: this code has been tested on matplotlib 3.0.1 only

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (specifically plotting from the mesh).  Your answer is straightforward and to the point.  I tested the code on matplotlib 2.2.5 also, and it works fine.  Thank you very much for your help and clear answer.  (In one hour, stackoverflow will let me award you the 100 point bounty, I will do so ASAP.)

Comment: Please see my new post, and please help if you can : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68276852/reproducing-matplotlib-gallery-3d-plot-using-a-different-method.  Thank you so much.  It's very similar to this post, but I wanted to make a new question instead of asking you more (possibly different) questions about it.

Comment: How come this answer doesn't use the command np.meshgrid?

Comment: Well, you started using linspace (which wasn't wrong) and I focused on the obvious mistakes :-)