# 3d quiver plot from .npy data files to give a 3d vector field

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, matplotlib-3d

I want to plot a 3d velocity vector field using a 3d quiver plot in python, from 3 data  files (.npy) that give u, v and w components of velocity in the x, y and z directions. This what I have done so far, showing the error message as well. How do I create a 3d quiver plot from three 3d .npy data files? I have also looked at other examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62433465/how-to-plot-3d-point-clouds-from-an-npy-file) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68230004/making-a-3d-quiver-plot-using-matplotlib-by-reading-in-data). The code below was adapted from the 2d quiver plot example from [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/quiver_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-quiver-demo-py).

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import proj3d

c1 = 1
nx, ny, nz = 284, 160, 160

x1 = range(nx)
y1 = range(ny)
z1 = range(nz)

U = np.load("u.npy") # 3d array file
V = np.load("v.npy") # 3d array file
W = np.load("w.npy") # 3d array file

X1, Y1, Z1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1, z1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_title("pivot='mid'; every 10th arrow; units='velocity vector' time=" + str(c1))
Q = ax.quiver(X1[::10, ::10], Y1[::10, ::10], Z1[::10, ::10], U[::10, ::10],
    V[::10, ::10], W[::10, ::10], pivot='mid', units='inches')

#Not sure if it should be formatted as below:
#Q = ax.quiver(X1[::10, ::10, ::10], Y1[::10, ::10, ::10], Z1[::10, ::10, ::10], U[::10, ::10, ::10],
            #V[::10, ::10, ::10], W[::10, ::10, ::10], pivot='mid', units='inches')
qk = ax.quiverkey(Q, 0.9, 0.9, 5, r'$1 \frac{m}{s}$', labelpos='E', coordinates='figure') #possibly for 2D (X, Y) only.
ax.scatter(X1[::10, ::10], Y1[::10, ::10], Z1[::10, ::10], color='c', s=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('3D_video_velocity_' + str(c1) + '.png')
```

Error message:

```
$ python3 test_3d_quiver_plot_1a.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_3d_quiver_plot_1a.py", line 69, in <module>
    Q = ax.quiver(X1[::10, ::10], Y1[::10, ::10], Z1[::10, ::10], U[::10, ::10],
  File "/home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 2628, in quiver
    bcast = np.broadcast_arrays(*input_args, *masks)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in broadcast_arrays
  File "/home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 264, in broadcast_arrays
    shape = _broadcast_shape(*args)
  File "/home/brendan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/lib/stride_tricks.py", line 191, in _broadcast_shape
    b = np.broadcast(*args[:32])
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape
```

The result should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Quite difficult to diagnose without having the files. Anyway, did you verify that `X1.shape == Y1.shape == Z1.shape == U.shape == V.shape == W.shape`?

Comment: @Davide_sd --- The debugger is saying the arrays are too big 58 MB each. U, V and W are shape (284, 160,160). X1, Y1 and Z1 are (160, 284, 160) for some reason. I tried adapting [3d code](https://krajit.github.io/sympy/vectorFields/vectorFields.html) as I think the above code is for 1d and 2d quiver plots only.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the above comment, to create a 3D quiver plot `X1, Y1, Z1, U, V, W` must have the same shape.

Try to modify the following lines of code:

```
import numpy as np
nx, ny, nz = 160, 284, 160

x1 = range(nx)
y1 = range(ny)
z1 = range(nz)

X1, Y1, Z1 = np.meshgrid(x1, y1, z1)
```

Note that I changed `nx, ny, nz = 284, 160, 160` to `nx, ny, nz = 160, 284, 160`. This should give `X1, Y1, Z1` the correct shape.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the error with the shape. I managed to plot the data adapting code [here by @tacaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420504/adding-colors-to-a-3d-quiver-plot-in-matplotlib), as I couldn't get it the above code to work. I will post the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following code produced a 3d quiver plot from 3 data files (3d arrrays in .npy files). The code was adapted from [@tacaswell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420504/adding-colors-to-a-3d-quiver-plot-in-matplotlib).

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

nx, ny, nz = 160, 284, 160

x1 = range(nx)
y1 = range(ny)
z1 = range(nz)

u = np.load("u.npy")
v = np.load("v.npy")
w = np.load("w.npy")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(x1, y1, z1)

# 3d quiver plot for every 5th data point
ax.quiver(x[::5, ::5], y[::5, ::5], z[::5, ::5], u[::5, ::5], 
    v[::5, ::5], w[::5, ::5], length=0.1, color = 'red', lw=2)

plt.show()
```

The resultant 3d quiver plot is shown here (I haven't worked out how make the arrows larger yet):[image]